# Minimax tree where a player can move multiple times in a row

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, minimax

Having played around with turn-based games using Minimax and Alpha-Beta Pruining, how would one handle games where the same player can have multiple consecutive moves if some condition is met?

Comment: If the player has another move, he'll just try to maximize his next move instead of minimizing as in the case it were the opponent's move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If player `A` is invoking minimax then:

On Player `A`'s **first** turn of a run: *maximise*

On Player `A`'s **second** turn of a run: *maximise* again.

This relies of objective evaluations of the board being based from the perspective of `A`. So regardless of whose turn it is on a state, `objective(state)` is with reference to `A`'s gain from that state.

You will need a way to determine given a sate `X`, was there a turn made  in the parent state such that the current turn for player `Z` is the second in a *row*. However you could also simply evaluate whose turn it is, and if it's `A`'s then perform maximisation as normal.

Comment: What about Alpha-Beta Pruning in this case, do I still do it as I would normally do?

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it most natural to consider a sequence of moves by one player as one action in the game tree?

Consider a game like Chinese Checkers. You would not consider each jump as a full move. You will consider a full move as the sequence of jumps for one pearl from it's start position to it's end position.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like checkers?

Minimax tree should have all the possible moves. If some condition is met, than i has to be also added like other possibilities. And all intermediate states have to be ignored